# How to split after some specific word

Tags: java

I have to split word when find `^` and `_live` in String. I am able to split only match `^` but I have to split when match `^` and `_live`. The result should be

```
[ab,cb,db,qw]
```

How will be done?

```
String usergroup="ab_live^cb_live^db_live^qw_live";
String[] userGroupParts = usergroup.split("\\^");                
List<String> listUserGroupParts = Arrays.asList(userGroupParts);
Set<String> SMGroupDetails = new HashSet<String>(listUserGroupParts);
```

Answer (score 1):

We can say that split separator should be **_live^** or just **_live** at the end of the line.

That's why regular expression must consist of _live and capturing group (\^|$) witch includes two alternatives separated by | (or):

1st alternative \^ matches the character ^ literally (by using escape character before) and 2nd alternative $ asserts position at the end of a line.

```
String[] userGroupParts = usergroup.split("_live(\\^|$)");
```

Comment: Please share more details such that others can learn from your answer

Comment: @Nico Haase, yes I put some explanation of my solution.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String usergroup = "ab_live^cb_live^db_live^qw_live";
    String[] userGroupParts = usergroup.split("\\^");
    for (int i=0; i<userGroupParts.length; i++) userGroupParts[i] = userGroupParts[i].split("\\_")[0];
    for (String s : userGroupParts) System.out.println(s);
}
```

i.e. you first split by ^ and then you cycle through the resulting strings splitting on _, retaining only the bit prior to the underscore

Comment: What is "this"? Please share more details such that others can learn from your answer

Comment: Its rather self explanatory: you first split by ^ and then you cycle through the resulting strings splitting 0n _, retaining only the bit prior to the underscore...

Comment: Then it should not be too hard to add all such explanation to your answer by editing it

Answer (score 0):

I would not use method [split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-), of class `java.lang.String`, but rather [regular expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/).

You want to create a list of all the occurrences of the letters that appear after the literal character `^` and before the string `_live`. The following code achieves this. (Explanations after the code.)

```java
/* Required imports:
 * java.util.ArrayList
 * java.util.List
 * java.util.regex.Matcher
 * java.util.regex.Pattern
 */
String usergroup="ab_live^cb_live^db_live^qw_live";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\^?(\\w+)_live");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(usergroup);
List<String> listUserGroupParts = new ArrayList<>();
while (matcher.find()) {
    listUserGroupParts.add(matcher.group(1));
}
System.out.println(listUserGroupParts);
```

The regular expression, i.e. the argument to method `compile` in the above code, looks for the following:

1. the literal character `^`, followed by
2. at least one word character, followed by
3. the literal string `_live`

Note that part 2 is surrounded by brackets which means it is referred to as a group.

The `while` loop searches `usergroup` for the next occurrence of the regular expression and each time it finds an occurrence, it extracts the contents of the group and adds it to the [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

The output when running the above code is:

```
[ab, cb, db, qw]
```